# Workbench & Data Loader access

Tags: data-loader, workbench

How can you restrict users from letting them access Workbench & Data Loader?

Comment: Workbench & Dataloader calls API and it can be restricted by restricting API access for user, but unfortunately, currently there's no option to do that in Salesforce and this idea has been already posted in success community which is currently under threshold point. you can certainly vote and help to get this implemented in future release of Salesforce. 

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jlwXAAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done at the profile level. Make sure the user is in a profile that has the profile "API Enabled" checkbox set to false.
Setup> Profiles > System Permission > API Enabled